In Angular 17 we are unable to load images from assets folder which we usually use to place in src of the root directory

So currently if I place assets in src my assets folder path is not being read.
**
The only solution I could find for it was to place the assets inside the pubic folder (because I found the favicon icon placed there in this version)
**

This is happening with recent Angular 17 repositories, in my old angular 17 repositories I did not have to change the path of assets folder.

Place the assets folder inside the pubic folder (because I found the favicon icon placed there in this version) and it will than recognize the assets.
This issue was found in Angular 17

